# Address Value Object (DDD) is not updating when I call var updatedEntity = await _repository.UpdateAsync(updateGuest, true); in Abpframework project

Tags: domain-driven-design, blazor-server-side, abp, persist

I'm having an issue with updating my record which is hindering my implementation of DDD in Abpframework. I'm using Guest object which OwnsOne Address. I'm able to add new address but when I use the following code to update the Guest and it's address the address part doesn't get updated. Can someone please help me solve this issue. Please my code below:

```
    var updateGuest = await _repository.GetAsync(request.Id, true);

    // Update the guest properties
    updateGuest.FirstName = request.FirstName;
    updateGuest.LastName = request.LastName;
    updateGuest.Email = request.Email;
    updateGuest.PhoneNumber = request.PhoneNumber;
    updateGuest.DateOfBirth = request.DateOfBirth;

    // Update the address properties
    updateGuest.Address.Street = request.Street;
    updateGuest.Address.City = request.City;
    updateGuest.Address.Country = request.Country;
    updateGuest.Address.ZipCode = request.ZipCode;

    var updatedEntity = await _repository.UpdateAsync(updateGuest, true);

    var updatedGuestDto = updatedEntity.Adapt<CreateUpdateGuestDto>();

    return updatedGuestDto;
```

Many thanks

Comment: Try assigning `updateGuest.Address = ...` instead of updating individual `Address` attributes.

Comment: Thanks @aaron Please see my changes here. Still not updating. When I step through my code the changes even after calling update method. but the changes doesn't persist to the database                                                                                                  
               `var uaddress = new Address(request.Street, 4, request.City, request.Country, 
                 request.ZipCode);
                updateGuest.Address = uaddress;
            // Save the changes to the repository
                var updatedEntity = await _repository.UpdateAsync(updateGuest, true);`

Comment: Edit your question to show the code for your `Address` class.

Comment: Thanks @aaron for your help. There guys are at Abp.io have helped me to fixed the issue by adding the following referrencies : **ApplicationService, ITransientDependency,** to my handler.